# How to determine if some $x$ is a generator of a subgroup of $Z^{*}_{y}$ of order $a$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Suppose we have integers $x,y$ and the prime factorization of $y-1$, and further suppose that $a$ is the largest prime factor of $y-1$ and that $y$ is prime. How do you determine if $x$ is a generator of a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{y}$ of order $a$?

Comment: The largest factor of $y-1$ is $y-1$. But that's not what you mean, is it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, it was supposed to be the largest prime factor.

Comment: Then please edit that into the statement of the problem, so no one has to hunt through the comments to find it. Any thoughts about the answer I posted?

Comment: @GerryMyerson How does the prime factorization of $y-1$ play into this? Is it even necessary?

Comment: I believe my answer works for any divisor $a$ of $y-1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson divisor $a$ or $d$? Also, is it necessary to check every value from $1$ to $y-1$ for divisors, or is the prime factorization sufficient?

Comment: Your question is about $a$, my answer is about $a$. If you have the prime factorization of $y-1$, and therefore the prime factorization of $a$, then you have the prime factors $q$ of $a$, and you need only check $x^{a/q}$ for all those $q$.

Comment: Must $q$ divide $a$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Also, isn't $a$'s prime factorization just equal to $a$, since $a$ is prime?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot we had decided $a$ is prime. Whether $a$ is prime or not, if $x^a\equiv1\pmod y$, then you only have to compute $x^{a/q}$ for prime divisors $q$ of $a$ to decide whether $x$ generates the subgroup of order $a$. And of course if $x^a$ isn't 1 (mod $y$), you don't have to check anything.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you! So among the list of prime factors, I only need the ones that divide $a$? That is, I don't have to check every divisor of $a$, just the prime factor divisors?

Comment: Well, think about it; if $x^{a/d}$ is 1, and $q$ is a prime divisor of $a$ and of $d$, then $a/q$ is a multiple of $a/d$, so $x^{a/q}$ is a power of $x^{a/d}$, so it's also 1.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But if $a$ is prime, aren't it's only prime divisors itself and $1$?

Comment: 1 is not a prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we have that the order of $\mathbb{Z}_y^{*}$ is $y-1$. Indeed, $\mathbb{Z}_y^{*}$ consists of $y-1$ elements: all integers modulo $y$ except the zero.

By Lagrange's theorem, we know that the order of every subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb{Z}_y^{*}$ divides the order of $\mathbb{Z}_y^{*}$. So if the order of $G$ is $a$, then $a$ is a divisor of $y-1$.

Now if you want to know whether an element $x \in G$ is a generator of $G$, you just have to check whether the order of $x$ is $a$, that is, check if the least positive integer $t$ such that $x^t=1 \pmod{y}$ is $t=a$.

Answer (score 1):

You look at $x^{a/d}$ modulo $y$ for each divisor $d$ of $a$ (I guess each prime divisor would do). $x$ is what you want if $x^a$ is one and no $x^{a/d}$ is one.